# How to optimize mysql insert into queries, which are done every visit?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

i have a website, where it is necessary to do an insert into query on every new user visit. It is a session table which contains necessary informations such as language and other site settings. However these queries take a long time, and once they expire, it has to be done again. 
Basicly it is 'INSERT INTO ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE'
Session table is INNODB, and columns are:
session_id(varchar(255)), session_expires(int(10, unsigned), session_data(text)

Because of this loading the site for the first time(and when session expires) takes so long . Query time sometimes 20-40 seconds!

Answer (score 0):

Ok i solved my problem by using memcache to handle my session data. That is the best solution!